# When I pass a pointer I lose all methods available on that interface

Tags: pointers, go

I have a task when I need to pass a pointer across one application (a custom kubernetes controller) - it reads crd every 60 seconds and modifies that interface.
The problem is that when I pass a pointer I loose all methods available on that interface.

It's related to client-go/cache cache.Store

Is there a way to call methods on a pointer?

```
        package main

        import (
            "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
        )

        func main() {
            store := cache.NewStore(cache.DeletionHandlingMetaNamespaceKeyFunc)
            writeObject(&store)
        }

        func writeObject(store *cache.Store) {
            store.
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "lose all methods"? Are you trying to do a type assertion on the passed pointer and it fails? What happens when you do the same assertion on the value  of the pointer, eg. `(*pointer).(YourInterface)`? Can you include some example code on what you tried (and error messages) and a link to `cache.Store` (godoc)?

Comment: An interface is defined by its methods, so it's impossible to "lose" them. Add an example to your question that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you talking about a pointer to interface? If so you can call methods after indirection: '(*intf).Method()'

Comment: Maybe you have interace methods using value receiver instead of pointer as specified https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers here you should use pointer reciever on all methods for consistency. And please specify example code for understanding

Comment: Added code to the post

Answer (score 0):

Your [`store` is already a pointer](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/787fa2adce7cc0b0780acdefda3255c8adf8765c/tools/cache/store.go#L232-L235), so passing a `*cache.Store` is possible, but not useful.

When accepting a [`cache.Store`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache#Store), you should be able to access its methods the normal way, e.g.

```
func writeObject(store cache.Store) {
    err := store.Add(...)
}
```